# Having problems creating cookie javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Currently, I have a checkbox and once someone clicks on that checkbox, both the checkbox and label will disappear and some content will take its place. I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to finish setting it up so that if the cookie does exist, it will hide the checkbox. And if the cookie doesn't exist, it will show the checkbox and upon clicking it will remember the user's choice for 30 days.

Here's the Javascript:

```
   function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

createCookie('distributorcheckbox','cookie',30);

var x = readCookie('distributorcheckbox')
if (x) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("label").addClass("important");
        $('input[type="checkbox"][value="red"]').hide( "fast", function() {
    $(".red").show();
        $(this).closest('label').hide()
         });
        });
}
else {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][value="red"]').click(function () {
        $(".red").show();
        $(this).closest('label').hide()
    });
});
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div>
<label><input name="colorCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="red" />testing</label></div>
<div class="red box">
test
</div>
```

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zs1sn362/7/

UPDATE: I believe I got the cookie to work, but now the checkbox doesn't show if the cookie doesn't exist.

Comment: You should also wrap the `if` part around `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: I did that, but now it doesn't show the checkbox even if you haven't clicked it yet. I updated the post with the updated code and I put a link to JSfiddle

Comment: You are creating the cookie by calling `createCookie('distributorcheckbox','cookie',30);` so it always exists, no?  I think that should be in the bottom part, after hiding the label when the user clicks the checkbox.

Comment: I want the cookie to exist for 30 days after you check the checkbox.

Comment: Yes after you check it - but you have it in the wrong place.

Comment: Could you be more specific on where I should put it?

Answer (score 0):

You were creating the cookie before any action took place. This will show checkbox until it is clicked.

JS:

```
   function createCookie(name, value, days) {
       if (days) {
           var date = new Date();
           date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
           var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
       } else var expires = "";
       document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
   }

   function readCookie(name) {
       var nameEQ = name + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
           var c = ca[i];
           while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
           if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
       }
       return null;
   }

   function eraseCookie(name) {
       createCookie(name, "", -1);
   }

   var x = readCookie('distributorcheckbox');
   console.log(x);
   if (x) {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("label").addClass("important");
           $('input[type="checkbox"][value="red"]').hide("fast", function () {
               $(".red").show();
               $(this).closest('label').hide()
           });
       });
   } else {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('input[type="checkbox"][value="red"]').click(function () {
               createCookie('distributorcheckbox', 'cookie', 30);
               $(".red").show();
               $(this).closest('label').hide()
           });
       });
   }
```

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/zs1sn362/10/)

Comment: Thanks, but now the content that is supposed to be hidden until the checkbox is checked now shows. I need that content only to show if the checkbox is clicked and if the cookie exists.

Comment: That is from a lack of css hiding the `.red` class before you show it with the JS. Check the new JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/zs1sn362/10/